# Create a temp table with pre-filled columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to create a temp table `#TempTable` with columns. There are many columns and I do not want to type them all out by hand. Is there a way to pre-fill, if that makes sense?

**Instead of**

```
CREATE #TempTable (col1, col2 ... col1000) -- Im not saying we have 1000
```

**But doing:**

```
CREATE #TempTable (SELECT column_name 
                   from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'OriginalTable')
```

Is this possible? Im using MS SQL.

Comment: right click on a table in the format you are interested in, the 'script table as -> CREATE -> New Window' then you have a nice Create statement that you can edit to be a temp table - then you have some nice flowery code, and you look diligent

Comment: right-click? Im using phpstorm and terminal ;)

Comment: does it give you the capability to script out the DB or table?

Comment: Ohh yes I see what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `SELECT . . . INTO` :

```
SELECT ot.* INTO #TempTable 
FROM OriginalTable ot
WHERE 1 = 0;
```

Note : When using the `SELECT . . . INTO` statement, the `#TempTable`  must not already exist.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing -

```
select top 0 * into #TempTable from OriginalTable
```

The above creates an empty copy of temp table

If you don't want to specify *(wildcard) and want specific columns from OriginalTable to be created in your temporary table -

```
select top 0 col1,col2,col3 into #TempTable from OriginalTable
```

Answer (score 1):

When creating a temp table, it's good to clean up before creating it. repeating this step will cause an error if the table already exists

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmp

select * 
into #tmp 
from OriginalTable
```